# Understanding the difference between data contracts and business entites

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity, business-logic

I was hoping someone could help alleviate some confusion I am having around WCF.  I have a  WCF service. The first thing I am doing is creating a data contract Let's say my data contract is "Customer".  I seem to understand the data contracts.

Now I don't want to use a Message Contract, so I go straight to creating the Service contract...ICustomerService...with an operation called GetCustomer.  But what should the return type be?  Should it be a return type of DataContracts.Customer? This is where I get confused as to the difference between business entities and data contracts.  Three  questions:

1. Is a data contract not a business entity?
2. Let's say I did have a customer business entity called "CustomerInformation" in the BusinessLogic project.  As far as  the ServiceContract project goes, it doesn't have any knowledge of the BusinessLogic project, which leads me to believe that it wouldn't be the proper architecture to add a reference to the business logic project so it can see the business entity.  I see that the ServiceImplementation project, however, DOES have a business logic reference.
3. If I did have a CustomerInformation business entity, wouldn't it look exactly the same as my DataContracts.Customer data contract?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data
   Your data contract is represented by an interface that defines how the outside world can pass data to your service. Your business entity is a class that holds data that is passed around and processed inside your BL layer.
2. In many cases the service implementation contains the BL. If your service implementation is in a separate service layer, it probably still shares entities with your BL layer. You are right about not referencing the BL from the service contract project (and it is right to have a separate project for the contract).
3. Possibly yes, they could have the exact same attributes, but they don't have to. Your business entity could have additional properties that are only used for internal processing.